# Get access to response that is formed by webpage after it loads

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, response-headers

I want to analize responses and requests, that are made by webpage. For example while opening devtools in chrome i see a lot of requests like on the screen [image]
How can i access and read any request or response using python. I was trying requests and selenium, but have no solution

Comment: What you're looking for is a "web proxy".  Essentially, every web request would go through your app, which would then forward it on.   There are lots of examples of simple web proxies in Python.  For example, https://github.com/luugiathuy/WebProxyPython